# error LGHT0204: ICE03 while writing XPath query to get empty nodes

Tags: xpath, wix

I am trying to write an XPath query in my Wix installer to select node with zero child elements.
My Element path looks like this as it's a formatted string and I escape square braces.

```
ElementPath="a/b[\[]not(node())[\]"
```

whieh I believe translates to

> `a/b[not(node())]`

My xml is of the form

```
<a>
  <b><x/><y/></b>
  <b/>
  <b><z/></b>
</a>
```

and I expect my Element path to select the second  element which has no children. Bit when I run light on my installer, it throws an invalid format error. Please suggest where I am going wrong.
Also , if I have to select a node with specific value, 
would this be the right way?

```
ElementPath="a/b[\[]z[\]"
```

so that I select the third  node  as child element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need another closing square bracket in the expression :

```
ElementPath="a/b[\[]not(node())[\]]"
```

Notice this part for escaping opening square bracket :

```
[\[]
```

And another important part for escaping closing square bracket :

```
[\]]
```

You can see each of the two important parts I mentioned above as escaped square bracket part `\]` enclosed within another square brackets `[]`. Put it all together and it become `[\]]`.